# Unable to set axios data in state

Tags: reactjs, axios

I had initialized datas state as null array. I am trying to fetch data from axios post method like

```
componentDidMount(){
    var a=this;
    axios.post("http://localhost/axios/index.php")
    .then((res)=>{
      a.setState({datas:res.data});
    });
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

I am receiving

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}}
0: {id: "1", typee: "class", user_id: "1"}
1: {id: "2", typee: "class", user_id: "1"}
2: {id: "3", typee: "course", user_id: "1"}
3: {id: "4", typee: "class", user_id: "2"}
4: {id: "5", typee: "test_series", user_id: "3"}
5: {id: "6", typee: "test_series", user_id: "2"}
```

this data if i console.log(res.data)
but if i console.log(this.state) then it's still giving me null array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, so when you are console logging it, state has not yet been updated. You can use the callback form of `setState` to get the updated state:

```
setState(
  { datas:res.data },
  () => console.log(this.state)
);
```

more info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate